# How do I create an XML document with an <!ENTITY> and a <!NOTATION> that XmlDocument.Load() can parse

Tags: .net, xml

I am trying to [serialize Xml to Bson](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-279). This means supporting all child classes of [System.Xml.XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx). However, I cannot figure out now to implement an xml document that has an [XmlEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlentity.aspx) or an [XmlNotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnotation.aspx) in it.

I tried parsing the html 4.0.1 strict dtd with XmlDocument.Load, but I got the following error:

```
System.Xml.XmlException : 'ENTITY' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'. Line 78, position 3.
```

Is there another way to end up with an XmlDocument that will have XmlEntity and XmlNotation child nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem, which Shellybutterfly began to point out with her suggestion to use SgmlReader, is that I was using a [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) dtd, not an xml dtd. I figured out the format of an xml dtd from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_dtd.asp).

I discovered you need to create an xml document, **with a root element** and declare the dtd in the [DOCTYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocumenttype.aspx). to be able to load it with [XmlDocument.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx). For my [test case](https://github.com/zippy1981/xml2json.Testcases/blob/master/xml2json/testcase.dtd) I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE contact
[
    <!NOTATION PublicNotation PUBLIC 'PublicId' >
    <!NOTATION SystemNotation SYSTEM 'SystemId' >
]>
<contact>
</contact>
```

I was able to use that in my [tests project](https://github.com/zippy1981/xml2json.Testcases/blob/master/xml2json/Main.cs).

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion if you can't find what you are looking for: I have been playing around with [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader), which has the built-in functionality with SgmlDtd to read in an SGML DTD, which is not the same as an XML DTD.

It includes an HTML .dtd modeled after 4.01 transitional, but made to account for more errors, which can parse even very poorly formed HTML.  ("Worse" than 4.01 transitional, I *believe* the example they give is a  tag in a  element.)

I digress; my actual point is that the HTML DTD is an SGML DTD which differs significantly from an XML dtd, so perhaps that's the issue? If so, I believe you should be able to load the XML DTD's .dtd, into the SgmlReader, which then should allow you to read in any Xml .dtd into the backing store that SgmlReader uses: an XmlDocument.  [edit: I found this [XmlSpec document from Oct 1, 2005 from www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/2002/xmlspec/dtd/2.10/xmlspec.dtd); it's the XML DTD; looking to see if I can figure out where the DTD .dtd is, or if it's somehow related...]

The primary intended use for it seems to be for fixing up ill-formed Html to go into Xml, but I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work as well.  Let me know if you have issues the code is a little dense in places but it was fairly simple once I got to know it better. [had some coffee, little wine, y'know...] :P

Good luck!

Comment: The [github repo](https://github.com/MindTouch/SGMLReader) claims to be GPL, but the [Code Gallery version](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SgmlReader) is MS-PL. I will look at that when the author clarifies.

Comment: been a while since I looked, but those licenses are correct. The other party took the original code (IIRC the bulk is identical) added some niceities then released GPL without renaming (seems a bit shi**y to me, but oh well, such are permissive licenses.) When I was using it, I just used the Code Gallery version.

BTW, the original statement, which I will let stand with this note, was based on HTML4... HTML5 makes HTML no longer SGML-based. (info: WHATWG: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html W3C: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#historical-notes )